# fatal error LNK1179: invalid or corrupt file: duplicate COMDAT '_IID_IXMLDOMImplementation'

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2005

I am getting this single error when I am linking my project,

> COMMUNICATION.obj : fatal error LNK1179: invalid or corrupt file:
>   duplicate COMDAT '_IID_IXMLDOMImplementation'

What is the source of the problem?

Comment: Have your tried to delete COMMUNICATION.obj and rebuild?

Comment: Yes I did it, but the same file gets recreated and it again gives the same error.

Answer (score 45):

This is a tricky one.

The issue is that the symbol(s)-generated is too-long, and an ambiguity exists:

```
  //...
  void MyVeryLongFunctionNameUnique_0(void);
  void MyVeryLongFunctionNameUnique_1(void);
  //   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  //   (example max-symbol-length-seen-by-linker)
```

In this case, the linker "sees" these two functions as the "same", because the part that makes them "unique" is longer-than-the-max-symbol length.

This can happen in *at least* three cases:

- Your symbol names are "too-long" to be considered unique to the linker, but may have been fine for the compiler (such as when you expand-out from many nested templates)
- You did some "trickery" that is invalid C++, and it passed the compiler, but you now have an invalid `*.obj`, and it chokes the linker.
- You specified duplicate "unnamed" classes/structs, and the linker cannot resolve them.
- **===[UPDATE]===**, It's not your fault, it's an internal problem with the compiler and/or linker (see below for possible work-arounds).

Depending on the issue (above), you can "increase" your symbol-length (by limiting-your-decrease-of-symbol-length), or fix your code to make it valid (unambiguous) C++.

This error is (minimally) described by Microsoft at:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cddbs9aw(v=vs.90).aspx

**NOTE:** This max-symbol-length can be set with the `/H` option, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bc2y4ddf(v=vs.90).aspx

- **RECOMMEND:**  Check to see if `/H` is used on your command-line.  If it is, delete it (do not specify max-symbol-length, it will default to `2,047`, the `/H` can only *DECREASE* this length, not *increase* it).

However, you probably triggered it through the `/Gy` option (function-level-linking), which was probably implied through one of `/Z7`, `/Zi`, or `/ZI`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/958x11bc(v=vs.90).aspx

One MSDN thread that talks about this issue is:

- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcmfcatl/thread/57e3207e-9fab-4b83-b264-79a8a717a8a7

This thread suggests that it's possible to trigger this issue with "invalid-C++-code-that-compiles" (you get your `*.obj`), but that invalid-`*.obj` chokes the linker (this example attempts to use `main` as both a function and as a template):

- http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/lounge/46361/

**===[UPDATE]===**

I should have said this before, because I suspected, but I now have more information:  It might not be your fault, there seems to be an issue in the compiler and/or linker that triggers this error.  This is despite the fact that the only common denominator in all your failed relationships is you.

Recall that the "above-list" applies (it MIGHT be your fault).  However, in the case where, "it's not your fault", here's the current-running-list (I'm confident this list is NOT complete).

- There is an internal error/corruption in your `*.ilk` file (intermediate-link-file).  Delete it and rebuild.
- You have `/INCREMENTAL` turned on for linking, but somehow that incremental-linking is not working for your project, so you should turn it off and rebuild (`Project-Properties=>Configuration Properties=>Linker=>General=>Enable Incremental Linking` [set to "No" (`/INCREMENTAL:NO`)]
- There's a problem with "Optimization" for "COMDAT Folding" in your use. Your can "Remove Redundant COMDATs" by going to `Project Proerties=>Configuration Properties=>Linker=>Optimization=>Enable COMDAT Folding`, set to "Remove Redundant COMDATs (`/OPT:ICF`)

Here's an interesting thread from a guy who *sometimes* can link, and sometimes not, by commenting in/out a couple lines of code.  It's not the code that is the problem -- he just cannot link consistently, and it looks like the compiler and/or linker has an internal problem under some obscure use case:

- http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/fatal-error-lnk1179-t1430593.html

Other observations from a non-trivial web search:

- this problem appears to be non-rare
- it seems to be related to some form of `template<>` use
- others seem to see this problem with "Release" build when it did not have this problem with "Debug" build (but it is also seen on the "Debug" build in many cases)
- if the link "fails" on one machine, it may "succeed" on another build machine (not sure why, a "clean-build" appears to have no effect)
- if you comment in/out a particularly significant couple-lines-of-code, and finish your build, and keep doing this until all the code is un-commented again, your link may succeed (this appears to be repeatable)
- if you get this error with MSVC2008, and you port your code to MSVC2010, you will still get this error

**===[PETITION TO THE GOOD PEOPLE OF THE WORLD]===**

If you have other observations on this error, please list them below (as other answers, or as comments below this answer).  I have a similar problem, and it's not my fault, and none of these work-arounds worked for me (although they did appear to work for others in their projects in some cases).

I'm adding a bounty because this is driving me nuts.

**===[UPDATE+2]===**

*(sigh)*, Here's more things to try (which apparently work for others, but did not work for me):

- this guy changed his compile settings, and it worked (from thread at http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?249603.html):

  `Project->Settings->C++ tab, Debug cathegory: Inline function expansion`: change from '`None`' to '`Only _inline`'.
- the above thread references another thread where the had to re-install MSVC
- it is possibly related to linking modules with "subtle-differences" in possibly-incompatible compiler and/or link switches.  Check that all the "contributing libs" are built with the exact same switches

Here's some more symptoms/observations on this error/bug:

- list(s) for above issues still apply
- the issue seems to "start-showing-up" with MSVC2005, and continues with the same behavior for MSVC2008 and MSVC2010 (error still occurs after porting code to newer compilers)
- restarting IDE, rebooting machine doesn't seem to work for anybody
- one guy said an explicit "clean" followed by a recompile worked for him, but many others say it did not work for them
- is often related to "incremental linking" (e.g., turn it off)

Status:  No joy.

**===[UPDATE+3 : LINK SUCCESS]===**

*Super-wacky-makes-no-sense **fix*** to successfully link discovered!

This is a variation on (above), where you "fiddle-with-the-code-until-the-compiler-and/or-linker-behaves".  NOT GOOD that one might need to do this.

Specific single linker-error (`LNK1179`) was for `MyMainBody<>()`:

```
#include "MyClassA.hpp"
#include "MyClassB.hpp"
#include "MyClassC.hpp"
#include "MyClassD.hpp"
#include "MyMainBody.hpp"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  // Use a function template for the "main-body", 
  // implementation is "mostly-simple", instantiates 
  // some local "MyClass" instances, they reference 
  // each other, and do some initialization,
  // (~50 lines of code)
  //
  // !!! LNK1179 for `MyMainBody<>()`, mangled name is ~236 chars
  //
  return MyMainBody<MyClassA,MyClassB,MyClassC,MyClassD>(argc,argv);
}
```

**THE FIX:**

- Convert `MyMainBody<>()` from a "`template<>`" to an **explicit function, LINK SUCCESS**.

**THIS FIX SUX**, as I need the EXACT-SAME-CODE for other types in other utilities, and the `MyMainBody<>()` implementation is non-trivial (but mostly simple) instantiations-and-setups that must be done in a specific way, in a specific order.

But hey, it's a temporary work-around for now:  Confirmed on MSVC2008 and MSVC2010 compilers (same `LNK1179` error for each, successful link on each after applying the work-around).

**THIS IS A COMPILER AND/OR LINKER ERROR**, as the code is "simple/proper-C++" (not even C++11).

So, I'm happy *(that I got a link after suffering full-time for 2+weeks)*.  But, disappointed *(that the compiler and/or linker has a STUPID GLARING PROBLEM with linking a SIMPLE TEMPLATE<> in this use-case that I couldn't figure out how to address)*.

**FURTHER, the "Bounty Ended"**, but nobody else wanted to take this on *(no other answers?)*, so looks like "**+100**" goes to nobody. *(heavy-sigh)*

Comment: I've just had this problem on VC.NET SP1.  I was using the same type library import to implement two COM coclasses, so I wanted to have just one implementation of the wrappers so I used the attributes .. `rename_namespace("CleanerName"), named_guids, no_implementation` and placed this in stdafx.h, and then used ..`implementation only` in on of the CPP files.  I then get your error on one of the IID definitions.  The moment I move it somewhere other than stdafx.h the error goes away.

Comment: Specifying /Ob1 or /Ob2 (enabled inlining) worked for me

Comment: But specifying inlining is not compatible with some debug flags, so in my case, I had to simplify the code.

Comment: This bug is happening with increased frequency in Chrome with VS 2015 - a new variant of the bug perhaps?

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1853228/lnk1179-invalid-or-corrupt-obj-file-created-by-vs-2015-rtm-compiler-in-debug-builds

Comment: Two years later; importing a type library using named_guids will sometimes cause this.

Answer (score 8):

This question has a lot of answers but none of them quite capture what was happening in my codebase, and what I suspect the OP was seeing back in 2012 when this question was asked.

## The Problem

The COMDAT error on an `IID_*` type is easy to accidentally reproduce by using the [`#import` directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/hash-import-directive-cpp) with both the [`rename_namespace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/rename-namespace) and [`named_guids`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/named-guids) attributes.

If two `#import`ed type libraries contain the same interface, as is likely the case for OP's `IXMLDOMImplementation`, then the generated `.tlh` files will declare `IID_IXMLDOMImplementation` in both namespaces, leading to the duplicate.

For example, the code generated for:

```
#import <foo.tlb> rename_namespace("FOO") named_guids;
#import <bar.tlb> rename_namespace("BAR") named_guids;
```

...could be simplified into something like this:

```
namespace FOO {
    extern "C" __declspec(selectany) const GUID IID_IFOOBAR = {0};
}

namespace BAR {
    extern "C" __declspec(selectany) const GUID IID_IFOOBAR = {0};
}
```

Here's a simple RexTester reproduction of the problem: https://rextester.com/OLAC10112

The `named_guids` attribute causes the `IID_*` to be generated and the `rename_namespace` attribute wraps it in the namespace.

Unfortunately, in this case, `extern "C"` does not seem to work as expected when it appears inside a C++ namespace. This causes the compiler to generate multiple definitions for `IID_FOOBAR` in the same `.obj` file.
[`DUMPBIN /SYMBOLS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/symbols) or a hex editor confirms the duplicate symbols.

The linker sees these multiple definitions and issues a `duplicate COMDAT` diagnostic.

## A Solution

Knowing that `rename_namespace` doesn't play well with `named_guids`, the obvious solution is to simply not use them together. It's probably easiest to remove the `named_guids` attribute and instead use the [`_uuidof()` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/uuidof-operator).

After removing `named_guids` from `#import` directives and touching up the code, replacing all uses of `FOO::IID_IFooBar` with `_uuidof(FOO::IFooBar)`, my COM-heavy codebase is back to building again.

Comment: I upvoted this answer years ago. Just ran into this issue again and found myself here. Wish I could upvote again, thanks!

Comment: Here I am again. Wish I could upvote this yet again. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This issue is reported as a bug in some specific versions of Visual Studio 2017. Try patching 15.9.1 or later to fix this issue

- [Reported Issue in VS 15.8 Preview 4](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/296073/lnk1179-duplicate-comdat-in-visual-studio-158-prev.html)
- [Resolved patchs in VS 15.9 Preview 2](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/topics/fixed+in%3A+visual+studio+2017+version+15.9+preview+2.html)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem whilst porting some code (1) from MSVC to GCC. To get the build to link on GCC, I had to provide empty implementations for some specialised templated functions (2), and this resulted in LNK1179 on MSVC. I was able to resolve by inlining the functions (3), i.e.

1. `template<> template<> void LongName1<LongName2>::FunctionName(boost::library::type1 & a, const unsigned int b);`
2. `template<> template<> void LongName1<LongName2>::FunctionName(boost::library::type1 & a, const unsigned int b) {};`
3. `template<> template<> inline void LongName1<LongName2>::FunctionName(boost::library::type1 & a, const unsigned int b) {};`

Answer (score 0):

I had to do
c++ -> code generation -> enable function - level linking -> no

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10694896)

Comment: Thanks! I'm not used to Stackoverflow. Anyway I cannot answer the author because I don't understand the source of the problem. So I just exposed a solution I found for if is useful to someone.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully my lame workaround will help someone: I make sure to manually delete ALL .obj AND intermediate build files (including at least .pch, .pdb, .tlog, .lastbuildstate and anything else just hanging out looking suspicious) and rebuild from scratch.

I suggest without evidence that having some files left over from a previous build tends to cause the problem to happen more frequently.  In my specific build system, I delete and recreate the .vcxproj and .sln files from scratch as well.

My own personal suspicion is that some kind of race condition exists in the build/link process between the time that intermediate files are read and the time they are written in a large project.  Again, I have no evidence this is true, but this is my only guess that seems to fit all the known facts of the bug.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote Outlook addins years ago and I was asked to write another.  Right off the bat, I ran into this problem and through a little process of elimination, I fixed mine.

It turns out that when you choose an extensibity project(I hand coded mine back in the day), it creates and save 2 objects that I was unaware of: DTE and DTE80.  To create the interfaces that manipulate these objects, they import directly from the DLLs in stdafx.h.  Being that I'm working on Outlook, I also needed to import a couple of interfaces: Office and Outlook.

So, seeing as this error popped up almost immediately after writing my first tidbits of code, I started over, and added one thing at a time.  The project blew chunks in the described way right after I added:

```
//Added mvc 
//The following #import imports MSO based on it's LIBID
#import "libid:2DF8D04C-5BFA-101B-BDE5-00AA0044DE52" version("2.2") lcid("0") rename_namespace("Office") raw_interfaces_only named_guids
using namespace Office;

//The following #import imports Outoloks Object lib based on it's LIBID
#import "libid:00062FFF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046" rename_namespace("Outlook") raw_interfaces_only named_guids 
using namespace Outlook;
```

So, seeing as I had no intention of figuring out the DTE stuff, I just commented out them and anything having to do with them:

```
//The following #import imports VS Command Bars based on it's LIBID
//  #import "libid:1CBA492E-7263-47BB-87FE-639000619B15" version("8.0") lcid("0") raw_interfaces_only named_guids

//The following #import imports DTE based on it's LIBID
//  #import "libid:80cc9f66-e7d8-4ddd-85b6-d9e6cd0e93e2" version("8.0") lcid("0") raw_interfaces_only named_guids

//The following #import imports DTE80 based on it's LIBID
//  #import "libid:1A31287A-4D7D-413e-8E32-3B374931BD89" version("8.0") lcid("0") raw_interfaces_only named_guids
```

After wandering around fixing the compile errors, it compiled and linked just fine.  I'm not suggesting this will work for everybody, but it worked for me.  Good luck to any who pass by here....

Answer (score 0):

I got this error and was really confused about it. Ended commenting out everything in the referenced cpp and reintroduce things in small batches until the file was back in the same state as when I started. And I don't get the error anymore. To me this points to this in my case being a bug in the compiler but since I can't reproduce it anymore I can't get help further than that.

I'm on:
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019
Version 16.11.3