# How to avoid boost::phoenix when generating with boost::spirit::karma

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-bind, boost-phoenix

I'm a victim of error "LNK1179: invalid or corrupt file: duplicate COMDAT" 
and [these](https://gist.github.com/edouarda/2881295) [sources](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13495187/27596) lead me to believe that by not using `phoenix` I could avoid this error.

(This is a follow-up to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16603721/27596).)
I want to replace `boost::phoenix` with something else. Maybe `boost::bind` but I don't see how I can give it access to `karma::_val`.

The following code fails to compile on VC9 with

> error C2825: 'F': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::'

```
#include <boost/config/warning_disable.hpp>

#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <boost/assign/list_of.hpp>
#include <boost/range/adaptors.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm.hpp>

#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/karma.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>

#include <boost/bind.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>


namespace karma = boost::spirit::karma;
namespace spirit = boost::spirit;
namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;
namespace phoenix = boost::phoenix;


class Item
{
public:
    typedef std::vector<int> Values;

    Item(const std::string  & i, const Values & v) : m_id(i), m_values(v) {}
    std::string getId() const { return m_id; }
    const Values & getValues() const { return m_values; }

private:
    std::string m_id;
    Values m_values;
};

class ItemList
{
public:
    typedef std::map<std::string, Item> Items;

    ItemList() {}
    ItemList(const Items & s, const Items & o) : m_some(s), m_other(o) {}
    const Items getSome() const { return m_some; }
    const Items getOther() const { return m_other; }

private:
    Items m_some;;
    Items m_other;
};

template <typename Iterator>
struct list_generator : karma::grammar<Iterator, ItemList()>
{
    list_generator(const ItemList & i)
        : list_generator::base_type(start)
{
    using karma::int_;
    using karma::_1;
    using karma::lit;
    using karma::_val;

    // using phoenix causes: fatal error LNK1179: invalid or corrupt file: duplicate COMDAT '?value@?$result_@U?$member_variable@$$A6E?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZP8Item@@AE?AV12@XZ@detail@phoenix@boost@@@?$is_mem_fun_pointer_select@$0A@@detail@boost@@2_NB'
    // this is probably because the symbol names are too long.


    // Convert maps into lists containing only the values
    const Items some  = boost::copy_range<Items>(i.getSome() | boost::adaptors::map_values);
    const Items other = boost::copy_range<Items>(i.getOther() | boost::adaptors::map_values);

    id =
        lit("<id>")
        << karma::string
        << lit("</id>");

    values =
        lit("<values>") 
        << (int_ % ';') 
        << lit("</values>");

    item =
        lit("<item>")
        //<< id[_1 = phoenix::bind(&Item::getId, _val)]
        << id[boost::bind(&Item::getId, &_val, _1)] // !! error C2825 !!
        << values[_1 = phoenix::bind(&Item::getValues, _val)]
        << lit("</item>");

    start =
        lit("<some>")     << (*item)[_1 = some] << lit("</some>")
        << lit("<other>")  << (*item)[_1 = other] << lit("</other>");
}

typedef std::vector<Item> Items;
karma::rule<Iterator, std::string()> id;
karma::rule<Iterator, Item::Values()> values;
karma::rule<Iterator, Item()> item;
karma::rule<Iterator, ItemList()> start;
};

int main()
{
    const Item::Values values = boost::assign::list_of(1)(2)(3);
    const Item a("a", values);
    const Item b("b", values);

    ItemList::Items some, other;
    some.insert(std::make_pair(a.getId(), a));
    other.insert(std::make_pair(b.getId(), b));
    const ItemList items(some, ItemList::Items());

    typedef std::back_insert_iterator<std::string> Iter;
    typedef list_generator<Iter> Generator;

    Generator grammar(items);

    std::string generated;
    Iter sink(generated);
    if (!karma::generate(sink, grammar))
    {
        std::cout << "Generating failed\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Generated: " << generated << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The full error is this:

```
error C2825: 'F': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::'
1>        c:\path\to\boost\boost/bind/bind_template.hpp(15) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::_bi::result_traits<R,F>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            R=boost::_bi::unspecified,
1>            F=std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> (__thiscall Item::* )(void) const
1>        ]
1>        .\spiritTest.cpp(85) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::_bi::bind_t<R,F,L>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            R=boost::_bi::unspecified,
1>            F=std::string (__thiscall Item::* )(void) const,
1>            L=boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<boost::phoenix::actor<boost::phoenix::composite<boost::phoenix::reference_eval,boost::fusion::vector<boost::spirit::attribute<0>,boost::fusion::void_,boost::fusion::void_,boost::fusion::void_,boost::fusion::void_,boost::fusion::void_,boost::fusion::void_,boost::fusion::void_,boost::fusion::void_,boost::fusion::void_>>>>,boost::_bi::value<boost::spirit::_1_type>>
1>        ]
1>        .\spiritTest.cpp(57) : while compiling class template member function 'list_generator<Iterator>::list_generator(const ItemList &)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            Iterator=Iter
1>        ]
1>        .\spiritTest.cpp(116) : see reference to class template instantiation 'list_generator<Iterator>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            Iterator=Iter
1>        ]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use `boost::bind` expressions as a phoenix actor.

With regards to the long mangled names, I wouldn't be surprised if the use of other TMP-heavy libraries contribute significantly (e.g. Boost Range, which has it's own forest of template instantiations returning views from adaptors etc.).

You could try

1. Adapting the `Item` struct to a *fusion sequence*: (with or without `attr_cast<>`)

   - Along similar same lines, you could make the `item` rule *itself* consume a *fusion sequence* directly
2. To 'precook' an actor for use in the semantic action, either

   - using a Polymorphic Function Object (a.k.a. *deferred calleable object*)
   - or using a free function
3. Bake custom `phoenix::function<>` actors for `getId()` and `getValues()` (for completeness)

In the following, I demonstrate all of the approaches, concluding with a full sample program that includes all of these options, and was compiled with gcc 4.5.3 on windows (Cygwin).

---

#### 1. Adapting the `Item` struct to a *fusion sequence*:

```
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_ADT(Item,
        (std::string,         std::string,         obj.getId(),     (void)val)
        (Item::Values const&, Item::Values const&, obj.getValues(), (void)val)
    )

// the rule becomes simply
item =
    lit("<item>")
    << id      // yay for fusion magic!
    << values
    << lit("</item>");
```

This might actually make things equally bad internally - it's hard to tell from my vantage point. If it does, you could try to pry apart the phase where the attributes are consumed in the parse-expressions and the place where the `fusion adapter proxies` are evaluated:

```
item =
    lit("<item>")
    << karma::attr_cast<boost::fusion::vector<std::string, Item::Values> > // cast up front
    (
           id     // directly
        << values // 
    )
    << lit("</item>");
```

- Along similar same lines, you could make the `item` rule *itself* consume a *fusion sequence* directly instead of an `Item` instance. This is *sure* to remove all of the bind/proxy complexity from the parser expressions, **but** it requires more work to get the rest of the generators to connect.

#### 2. to 'precook' an actor for use in the semantic action, either

- using a Polymorphic Function Object (a.k.a. *deferred calleable object*):

  ```
  struct deferredGetId
  {
      template<typename,typename,typename> struct result { typedef void type; };

      template<typename Attr, typename Ctx, typename Bool>
      void operator()(Attr& attribute, Ctx const& context, Bool& flag) const
      {
          attribute = boost::fusion::at_c<0>(context.attributes).getId();
          flag = true;
      }
  };
  ```
- or using a free function. This then requires hard-coding the template argument for Context. A helpful explanation of the role of Spirit Context in karma rules may be found here: [boost spirit semantic action parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066701/boost-spirit-semantic-action-parameters/3067881#3067881)

  ```
  // non-template free function
  void hardcodedGetId(std::string& attribute, 
          boost::spirit::context<boost::fusion::cons<const Item&, boost::fusion::nil>, boost::fusion::vector0<> > const& context, 
          bool& flag)
  {
      attribute = boost::fusion::at_c<0>(context.attributes).getId();
      flag = true;
  }
  ```
- Note that there is also [BOOST_PHOENIX_ADAPT_FUNCTION](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/phoenix/doc/html/phoenix/modules/function/adapting_functions.html) that allows you to use a *function template* directly, but all that really does is wrap the function template inside a new Polymorphic Function Object type like above, so this will not gain you anything.

Now you could use those in your rules:

```
 item =
     lit("<item>")
     << id [_1 = phoenix::bind(&Item::getId, _val)] // works fine on GCC :)
     << id [deferredGetId()] // approach #1 (a)
     << id [hardcodedGetId]  // approach #1 (b)
     << values[_1 = phoenix::bind(&Item::getValues, _val)]
     << lit("</item>");
```

#### 3. Using `phoenix::function` to wrap deferred callables

Finally there is the option to use `phoenix::function` to wrap deferred callables directly as a (unary) actor. I'm not convinced it will actually help you, unless there is some kind of *erasure* going on that I'm not aware of. 
But the end result is pretty elegant, which in itself is a good reason to mention it, if only for completeness:

```
struct GetId
{
    template<typename> struct result { typedef std::string type; };
    template<typename Item>
    std::string operator()(Item const& item) const { return item.getId(); }
};

struct GetValues
{
    template<typename> struct result { typedef Item::Values type; };
    template<typename Item>
    typename Item::Values const& operator()(Item const& item) const { return item.getValues(); }
};

boost::phoenix::function<GetId>     phx_getId;
boost::phoenix::function<GetValues> phx_getValues;
```

This, you can then employ simply like this:

```
item =
    lit("<item>")
    << id[_1 = phx_getId(_val)]
    << values[_1 = phx_getValues(_val)]
    << lit("</item>");
```

### Full sample code

```
#include <boost/config/warning_disable.hpp>

#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <boost/assign/list_of.hpp>
#include <boost/range/adaptors.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm.hpp>

#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/karma.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>

#include <boost/bind.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>

#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>

namespace karma = boost::spirit::karma;
namespace spirit = boost::spirit;
namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;
namespace phoenix = boost::phoenix;

class Item
{
public:
    typedef std::vector<int> Values;

    Item(const std::string  & i, const Values & v) : m_id(i), m_values(v) {}
    std::string getId() const { return m_id; }
    const Values & getValues() const { return m_values; }

private:
    std::string m_id;
    Values m_values;
};

class ItemList
{
public:
    typedef std::map<std::string, Item> Items;

    ItemList() {}
    ItemList(const Items & s, const Items & o) : m_some(s), m_other(o) {}
    const Items getSome() const { return m_some; }
    const Items getOther() const { return m_other; }

private:
    Items m_some;;
    Items m_other;
};

/////////////////////////////////////////////
// 1. Adapting the `Item` struct

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_ADT(Item,
        (std::string,         std::string,         obj.getId(),     (void)val)
        (Item::Values const&, Item::Values const&, obj.getValues(), (void)val)
    )

/////////////////////////////////////////////
// 2. Precooking Actors

struct deferredGetId
{
    template<typename,typename,typename> struct result { typedef void type; };

    template<typename Attr, typename Ctx, typename Bool>
    void operator()(Attr& attribute, Ctx const& context, Bool& flag) const
    {
        attribute = boost::fusion::at_c<0>(context.attributes).getId();
        flag = true;
    }
};

// non-template free function
void hardcodedGetId(std::string& attribute, 
        boost::spirit::context<boost::fusion::cons<const Item&, boost::fusion::nil>, boost::fusion::vector0<> > const& context, 
        bool& flag)
{
    attribute = boost::fusion::at_c<0>(context.attributes).getId();
    flag = true;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////
// 3. phoenix::function

struct GetId
{
    template<typename> struct result { typedef std::string type; };
    template<typename Item>
    std::string operator()(Item const& item) const { return item.getId(); }
};

struct GetValues
{
    template<typename> struct result { typedef Item::Values type; };
    template<typename Item>
    typename Item::Values const& operator()(Item const& item) const { return item.getValues(); }
};

boost::phoenix::function<GetId>     phx_getId;
boost::phoenix::function<GetValues> phx_getValues;

template <typename Iterator>
struct list_generator : karma::grammar<Iterator, ItemList()>
{
    list_generator(const ItemList & i)
        : list_generator::base_type(start)
{
    using karma::int_;
    using karma::_1;
    using karma::lit;
    using karma::_val;

    // using phoenix causes: fatal error LNK1179: invalid or corrupt file:
    // duplicate COMDAT
    // '?value@?$result_@U?$member_variable@$$A6E?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZP8Item@@AE?AV12@XZ@detail@phoenix@boost@@@?$is_mem_fun_pointer_select@$0A@@detail@boost@@2_NB'
    // this is probably because the symbol names are too long.

    // Convert maps into lists containing only the values
    const Items some  = boost::copy_range<Items>(i.getSome() | boost::adaptors::map_values);
    const Items other = boost::copy_range<Items>(i.getOther() | boost::adaptors::map_values);

    id =
        lit("<id>")
        << karma::string
        << lit("</id>");

    values =
        lit("<values>") 
        << (int_ % ';') 
        << lit("</values>");

    item =
        lit("<item>")
     //
        << id[_1 = phoenix::bind(&Item::getId, _val)] // works fine on GCC :)
        << id [deferredGetId()]     // approach #2 (a)
        << id [hardcodedGetId]      // approach #2 (b)
        << id [_1= phx_getId(_val)] // approach #3
     //
        << values[_1 = phoenix::bind(&Item::getValues, _val)]
        << values[_1 = phx_getValues(_val)]
        << lit("</item>");

    item =
        lit("<item>")
        << id     // approach #1: using BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_ADT
        << values // approach #1: using BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_ADT
        << lit("</item>");

    // approach #2 _with_ attr_cast:
    item =
        lit("<item>")
        << karma::attr_cast<boost::fusion::vector<std::string, Item::Values> >
        (
               id     // 'native' fusion sequence access
            << values // 'native' fusion sequence access
        )
        << lit("</item>");

    start =
        lit("<some>")     << (*item)[_1 = some] << lit("</some>")
        << lit("<other>") << (*item)[_1 = other] << lit("</other>");
}

typedef std::vector<Item> Items;
karma::rule<Iterator, std::string()> id;
karma::rule<Iterator, Item::Values()> values;
karma::rule<Iterator, Item()> item;
karma::rule<Iterator, ItemList()> start;
};

int main()
{
    const Item::Values values = boost::assign::list_of(1)(2)(3);
    const Item a("a", values);
    const Item b("b", values);

    ItemList::Items some, other;
    some.insert(std::make_pair(a.getId(), a));
    other.insert(std::make_pair(b.getId(), b));
    const ItemList items(some, ItemList::Items());

    typedef std::back_insert_iterator<std::string> Iter;
    typedef list_generator<Iter> Generator;

    Generator grammar(items);

    std::string generated;
    Iter sink(generated);
    if (!karma::generate(sink, grammar))
    {
        std::cout << "Generating failed\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Generated: " << generated << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank your for this very insightful answer! Luckily the variant that applies the fusion magic works for me.