# How to find out what methods in auto-type arguments of lambda?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit

I have been wrestling with Boost.Spirit for a week. Forgive me for my ignorance about C++'s template metaprogramming, but I can't help to ask: How do you know what can you do with a variable if you don't know its god damn type? For example:

```cpp
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

qi::on_error<qi::fail>(rule,
  [](auto& args, auto& context, auto& r) {
    // what to do with args, context and r?
  }
);
```

It's not like Python, where you can use `dir()` or `help()` to get information about some variable. I know I can use `typeid(..).name()` to find out the type of a variable, but usually it turns out to be some long unreadable text like:

```
struct boost::fusion::vector<class boost::spirit::lex::lexertl::iterator<class boost::spirit::lex::lexertl::functor<struct boost::spirit::lex::lexertl::token<class std::_String_iterator<class std::_String_val<struct std::_Simple_types<char> > >,struct boost::mpl::vector<__int64,struct String,struct Symbol,struct boost::mpl::na,struct boost::mpl::na,struct boost::mpl::na,struct boost::mpl::na,struct boost::mpl::na,struct boost::mpl::na,struct boost::mpl::na,struct boost::mpl::na,struct boost::mpl::na,struct boost::mpl::na,struct boost::mpl::na,struct boost::mpl::na,struct boost::mpl::na,struct boost::mpl::na,struct boost::mpl::na,struct boost::mpl::na,struct boost::mpl::na>,struct boost::mpl::bool_<1>,unsigned __int64>,class boost::spirit::lex::lexertl::detail::data,class std::_String_iterator<class std::_String_val<struct std::_Simple_types<char> > >,struct boost::mpl::bool_<1>,struct boost::mpl::bool_<1> > > & __ptr64,class boost::spirit::lex::lexertl::iterator<class boost::spirit::lex::lexertl::functor<struct boost::spirit::lex::lexertl::token<class std::_String_iterator<class std::_String_val<struct std::_Simple_types<char> > >,struct boost::mpl::vector<__int64,struct String,struct Symbol,struct boost::mpl::na,struct boost::mpl::na,struct boost::mpl::na,struct boost::mpl::na,struct boost::mpl::na,struct boost::mpl::na,struct boost::mpl::na,struct boost::mpl::na,struct boost::mpl::na,struct boost::mpl::na,struct boost::mpl::na,struct boost::mpl::na,struct boost::mpl::na,struct boost::mpl::na,struct boost::mpl::na,struct boost::mpl::na,struct boost::mpl::na>,struct boost::mpl::bool_<1>,unsigned __int64>,class boost::spirit::lex::lexertl::detail::data,class std::_String_iterator<class std::_String_val<struct std::_Simple_types<char> > >,struct boost::mpl::bool_<1>,struct boost::mpl::bool_<1> > > const & __ptr64,class boost::spirit::lex::lexertl::iterator<class boost::spirit::lex::lexertl::functor<struct boost::spirit::lex::lexertl::token<class std::_String_iterator<class std::_String_val<struct std::_Simple_types<char> > >,struct boost::mpl::vector<__int64,struct String,struct Symbol,struct boost::mpl::na,struct boost::mpl::na,struct boost::mpl::na,struct boost::mpl::na,struct boost::mpl::na,struct boost::mpl::na,struct boost::mpl::na,struct boost::mpl::na,struct boost::mpl::na,struct boost::mpl::na,struct boost::mpl::na,struct boost::mpl::na,struct boost::mpl::na,struct boost::mpl::na,struct boost::mpl::na,struct boost::mpl::na,struct boost::mpl::na>,struct boost::mpl::bool_<1>,unsigned __int64>,class boost::spirit::lex::lexertl::detail::data,class std::_String_iterator<class std::_String_val<struct std::_Simple_types<char> > >,struct boost::mpl::bool_<1>,struct boost::mpl::bool_<1> > > const & __ptr64,struct boost::spirit::info const & __ptr64>
```

So there is only one method left: **refer to the documentation**. But here's the problem: Spirit's documentation is incomplete. In this example, It only say a few words about these arguments in the ["Error Handling Tutorial"](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/tutorials/mini_xml___error_handling.html):

> on_error declares our error handler:
>
> `on_error<Action>(rule, handler)`
>
> ...
>
> handler is the actual error handling function. It expects 4 arguments:
>
> | Arg | Description |
> | --- | --- |
> | first | The position of the iterator when the rule with the handler was entered. |
> | last | The end of input. |
> | error-pos | The actual position of the iterator where the error occurred. |
> | what | What failed: a string describing the failure. |

But as you can see, `on_error`'s second argument is not a 4-arguments function, but a 3-arguments function (args, context and r). Is the documentation wrong? Where can I find out the methods on these arguments? **Does Spirit has a per-funcion API Documentation?**

Comment: Setting aside some of your presentation, I have some sympathy for you - the learning curve for Boost Spirit is a steep one. I got to grips with it by reading the tutorial carefully, then writing some simple grammars. The Boost documentation is known for being scrappy. Good luck - hopefully @sehe will pick this one up, although you might want to make the question wording a little more professional. Have an upvote anyway.

Comment: @Bathsheba Thank you. I feel much better after seeing your words. It gives me some confidence to overcome these hurdles. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way:

```
qi::on_error<qi::fail>(rule,
  [](auto& args, auto& context, auto& r) {
       std::cerr << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
  }
);
```

On e.g. GCC this prints the full signature including deduced type arguments.

### Is the documentation wrong?

Note that it **DOES** expect 4 arguments:

```
using namespace qi::labels;
qi::on_error<qi::error_handler_result::fail>(rule, f_(_1, _2, _3, _4));
```

When you install a handler like `f_`:

```
struct F {
    using result_type = void;

    template <typename... Args>
    void operator()(Args&&...) const {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }
};

boost::phoenix::function<F> f_{};
```

It prints (**[Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e07c592c5a41e6e1)**):

```
"expected" -> true
void Parser::F::operator()(Args&& ...) const [with Args = {const char*&, const char* const&, const char* const&, const boost::spirit::info&}]
"unexpected" -> false
```

As you can see, the documentation is not wrong or incomplete. Your expectations were, because you didn't get that `handler` represent a *deferred function* aka. [Phoenix Actor](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/libs/phoenix/doc/html/phoenix/inside/actor.html). I guess the "devious" thing the documentation did was assume you'd **see** that from the actual example, which immediately precedes the documentation you quoted:

> ```
> on_error<fail>
> (
>     xml
>   , std::cout
>         << val("Error! Expecting ")
>         << _4                               // what failed?
>         << val(" here: \"")
>         << construct<std::string>(_3, _2)   // iterators to error-pos, end
>         << val("\"")
>         << std::endl
> );
> ```

Here, it seems quite obvious that the expression `std::cout << val("Error! Expecting ") << _4 << val(" here: \"") << construct<std::string>(_3, _2) << val("\"") << std::endl` is **not** literally "a function taking 4 arguments". It is a Phoenix expression defining an actor that takes 4 arguments, though.

You **did** find out that an actor is *in fact* still implemented in terms of a callable object. And it "takes" 3 arguments, which are the technical implementation details for Phoenix actors and the Spirit context arguments.

The problem was a disconnect of abstraction levels. The documentation documents the library interface, you accidentally looked at implementation details.

### TL;DR

A lambda is not a deferred Phoenix actor.

Learn more about how deferred actors work e.g. with semantic actions:

- https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/quick_reference/semantic_actions.html

Some answers on [SO] that highlight the relation between Actor signature, context and implementation signatures:

- [How to avoid boost::phoenix when generating with boost::spirit::karma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16607238/how-to-avoid-boostphoenix-when-generating-with-boostspiritkarma/16609770#16609770)
- [boost spirit semantic action parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066701/boost-spirit-semantic-action-parameters/3067881#3067881)

Comment: Here he is!͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏

Comment: And now I found some more time to explain why the documentation isn't wrong /cc @Bathsheba

Comment: Added some more backgrounders where the nitty gritty details are better explained, as well as a variety of choices on how to define actors; you have choices!

Answer (score 1):

It will generate a compile time error, but if you have a class template declaration like

```
template <typename T> struct get_type;
```

Then trying to create a `get_type` object with a provided type will generate an error and in the error message it will tell you what the type provide to `get_type` is.  For example using

```
int main()
{
    auto lambda = [](auto first, auto second, auto third) 
    { 
        get_type<decltype(first)>{}; 
        get_type<decltype(second)>{}; 
        get_type<decltype(third)>{};
    };
    lambda(A{}, B{}, int{});
}
```

produces an error message like

```
main.cpp:20:9: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct get_type<A>'
   20 |         get_type<decltype(first)>{};
      |         ^~~~~~~~
main.cpp:14:30: note: declaration of 'struct get_type<A>'
   14 | template <typename T> struct get_type;
      |                              ^~~~~~~~
main.cpp:21:9: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct get_type<B>'
   21 |         get_type<decltype(second)>{};
      |         ^~~~~~~~
main.cpp:14:30: note: declaration of 'struct get_type<B>'
   14 | template <typename T> struct get_type;
      |                              ^~~~~~~~
main.cpp:22:9: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct get_type<int>'
   22 |         get_type<decltype(third)>{};
      |         ^~~~~~~~
main.cpp:14:30: note: declaration of 'struct get_type<int>'
   14 | template <typename T> struct get_type;
      |                              ^~~~~~~~
```

which tells use `first` is an `A`, second is a `B` and `third` is an `int` as seen in this [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a6d2d64cfca5b4c7).