# How to check if a container passed to a function is sorted and sort it if not

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, vector, stl

I have this function we wrote some time ago:

```
template <class C, class T>
static inline bool findClosestObject( const C& container, const TimeUnit& now, T& object );
```

- `C` is a container of T elements
- `TimeUnit` is a class encapsulating date and time
- `T` is an object with a `TimeUnit` information

This function does a binary search (using `std::lower_bound`) in the container to find the closest object to `now`.

As we do a binary search, the container must be sorted. This function is used with many kind of containers (`C` can be `std::vector`, `std::set`, `std::map`...) in many places. Sometimes we use sorted `std::vector` rather than `std::set` because their memory management is faster and also for historical issue and compatibility with other piece of your code which is using vectors.

Problem is that I found a place in the code where a developer called `findClosestObject` with a container that was not sorted....nice bug...and I cannot safely identify all places where this could have been done.

So I now need to prevent that by sorting the container in this specific case where it's not (will be slow but will at least work and guarantee function returns what we want it to return)

So I tried to modify my function:

```
template <class C, class T>
static inline const C& fixOrder( const C& container, C& temp )
{
    if ( std::is_sorted( container.begin(), container.end() )
    {
        return container;
    }
    else
    {
        assert( false ); // to alert developper
        // in Release, fix the issue to have function work!
        temp = container;
        std::sort( temp.begin(), temp.end() );
        return temp;
    }
}

template <class C, class T>
static inline bool findClosestObject( const C& originalContainer, const TimeUnit& now, T& object )
{
    C temp;
    const C& container = fixOrder( originalContainer, temp );
    ...
    // leave old code unchanged
}
```

But this fails to compile when `C` is a `std::set` or a `std::map`. Because `std::sort` is not allowed for those kind of containers...

Can `fixOrder` be written in such a way that it would only do things for `std::vector` and not for other containers?

Comment: Why not add a overload for `std::vector<T>`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could just add a partial specialization for `std::set<T>` and `std::map<T1,T2>` for your template function:

```
// This one is called for every C not having a better specialization
template <class C>
static inline const C& fixOrder( const C& container, C& temp )
{
    if ( std::is_sorted( container.begin(), container.end() ))
    {
        return container;
    }
    else
    {
        assert( false ); // to alert developper
        // in Release, fix the issue to have function work!
        temp = container;
        std::sort( temp.begin(), temp.end() );
        return temp;
    }
}

// This one is called for std::set<T>
template<class T>
static inline const set<T>& fixOrder( const set<T>& container, set<T>& temp )
{
    return container;
}

// This one is called for std::map<T1, T2>
template<class T, class T2>
static inline const map<T, T2>& fixOrder( const map<T, T2>& container, map<T, T2>& temp )
{
    return container;
}
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22411782/1989995) has details about the template functions overload resolution.

Comment: By the way, as the goal is to guarantee container is always sorted, it's probably safer to have unspecialized version do the sorting, and have specialized versions for `set`/`map` that will do nothing (then we can add some specialized versions when needed, but we keep default behaviour to silently sort "all"). It may make sense to update your post to reflect that.

Comment: @jpo38 Agree, will fix

Comment: Nice. Thanx again for your help.

Answer (score 5):

[alexeykuzmin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41188027/598696) is simpler and should solve your issue. My answer below is slightly more complicated but it could be an interesting read for educational purposes.

---

> Can fixOrder be written in such a way that it would only do things for std::vector and not for other containers?

Yes! You can use [`std::enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) and an helper `is_specialization_of` trait:

```
template <typename, template <typename...> class>
struct is_specialization_of : std::false_type
{
};

template <template <typename...> class TTemplate, typename... Ts>
struct is_specialization_of<TTemplate<Ts...>, TTemplate> : std::true_type
{
};

template <class C>
static inline auto fixOrder(const C& x, C&)
    -> typename std::enable_if<is_specialization_of<C, std::vector>{}, const C&>::type
{
    std::cout << "C is a vector\n";
    return x;
}

template <class C>
static inline auto fixOrder(const C& x, C&)
    -> typename std::enable_if<!is_specialization_of<C, std::vector>{}, const C&>::type
{
    std::cout << "C is not a vector\n";
    return x;
}
```

With the above code...

```
int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    std::set<int> s;

    fixOrder(v, v);
    fixOrder(s, s);
}
```

...will print:

> C is a vector
>
> C is not a vector

[**wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Ij6CV9q0qq6w7ZEN)